# flexbox - reduce vertical spacing

Tags: css, flexbox

How to reduce the vertical spacing between text and make the text center aligned?

```css
.item{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 4px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
h3, h4{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <h3>Title1</h3> 
  <h4>Title2</h4>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h3>Title1</h3> 
  <h4>Title2</h4>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h3>Title1</h3> 
  <h4>Title2</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` and add `justify-content: center; flex-direction: column;`

```css
.item{
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 4px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
h3, h4{
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <h3>Title1</h3> 
  <h4>Title2</h4>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h3>Title1</h3> 
  <h4>Title2</h4>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h3>Title1</h3> 
  <h4>Title2</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: And where is my rewards :p